# Elements in composition of groups.

Tags: group-theory

Say $|A|=|B|=k$ and $A\cap B = id$ and $A,B$ are subgroups of $G$. $AB$ is then also a subgroup of $G$ provided that $A,B$ commute.

But what is $|AB|$?

Is it simply $k^2$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a general result on computing $HK$, even when it is not a subgroup.

> $$| AB | = \frac{|A||B|}{|A \cap B|}$$

This is merely a counting problem. First observe that $AB$ is a union of left (or right) cosets of $B$. Meanwhile, each coset of $B$ has $|B|$ elements so you just need to count the number of distinct cosets of the form $aB$, $a \in A$. You can compute this to be equal to $\frac{|A|}{|A \cap B|}$.

Comment: Which since $A \cap B = \{e\}$, $|A \cap B| = 1$ which means that $|AB| = {|A||B| \over |A \cap B|} = {k\cdot k \over 1} = k^2.$

Answer (score 2):

Define  $f\colon A\times B\to G$ by $f(a,b)=ab$. If $a_1b_1= a_2b_2$ then $a_2^{-1}a_1=b_2b_1^{-1}$ The last element is both in $A$ and $B$ and hence must be identity, by the hypothesis. SO the function $f$ is injective. This shows the number of elements must be $k^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the map $A\times B\to AB$ for which $(x,y)\mapsto xy$.  This is clearly surjective.  Suppose $x_1y_1=x_2y_2$,

$$\begin{align}
x_1y_1=x_2y_2 & \implies x_2^{-1}x_1=y_2y_1^{-1}\\
& \implies x_2^{-1}x_1=y_2y_1^{-1}=e\end{align}$$
because $x_2^{-1}x_1=y_2y_1^{-1}\in A\cap B$.

Therefore $x_1=x_2$ and $y_1=y_2$ and the map is injective, so
$$|AB|=|A\times B|=|A||B|.$$

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is $k^2$, let $f:A\times B\rightarrow G$ $f(a,b)=ab$. Suppose that $f(a,b)=ab=1$ this implies that $a=b^{-1}$ so $a\in A\cap B=\{1\}$ so $a=1=b$ and $f$ is injective, $f$ is surjective since $A$ commutes with $B$ thus every element of $AB$ is of the form $ab, a\in A, b\in B$.

Answer (score 0):

Also, there's this general fact:

If $A,B$ are finite subgroups of a group $G$, then $\left|AB \right|=\left|A \right|\left|B \right|/\left|A\cap B \right|$.

Note this is true regardless of whether $AB$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Comment: T.S.L beat me to the punch.